# Need javascript that add values together (live result), without clicking a = button

Tags: javascript, html, live

I need to make kind of a "calculator" with buttons, with the values 1 to 10. 
Then, when i for example press "1", a result box will display "1", and then when i press "4" the result will automatically print "5", without having to press a "=" button.

I only need it to add values together, and have a reset function.

Javascript is pretty new for me. I'm not so good at writing it yet, but i understand almost everything.

Really hope someone can help me!

This is my current code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table.calc {
     border: 2px solid #0034D1;
     background-color: #809FFF;
}
input.calc {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 5px;
}
</style>

<script>
function pushButton(buttonValue) {
     if (buttonValue == 'C') {
          document.getElementById('screen').value = '';
     }
     else {
          document.getElementById('screen').value += buttonValue;
     }
}
function calculate(equation) {
     var answer = eval(equation);
     document.getElementById('screen').value = answer;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<table class="calc" cellpadding=4>
<tr><td colspan=3><input class="calc" id="screen" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=1 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=2 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=3 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=4 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=5 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=6 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=7 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=8 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=9 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value=0 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value='.' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value='C' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
<td><input class="calc" type="button" value='+' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=3><input class="calc" type="button" value='=' onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('screen').value);"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: No, i'm about to make a webtool.

Comment: What should happen if you press `2` twice, should that then add `22` to the previous number, or simply add `2` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the JavaScript "feature" of concatenating strings together (string + number also equals string), so you need `parseInt` around each number. Also, since I'm using parseInt, need to set the screen value to 0 (zero) instead of ''

```
<input class="calc" id="screen" value="0" type="text">
```

then change this:

```
function pushButton(buttonValue) {
     if (buttonValue == 'C') {
          document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
     }
     else {
          document.getElementById('screen').value = 
            parseInt(document.getElementById('screen').value) + 
            parseInt(buttonValue);
     }
}
```

Note: Pressing . (dot) or + (plus) causes an error. I think you need to call a separate function when that's pressed.

Comment: Very helpful thank you. I wonder if theres is a way to make it work with values like 1,0023?

Comment: I thought about that. It would be confusing to the user, but you could trigger the addition after a preset amount of time passed following the last keypress (say 0.5 seconds). I would stick to "standard" behavior of regular calculators, doing the computation when = is pressed.

Comment: I'm not quite following you, sorry. Could you make a copy og the script from GreenGiant, and add the feature so i might understand it? - It would save my day :)

Comment: Try writing yourself first and post a new question when you get stuck. What I described would use setTimeout and clearTimeout, or you would need to keep variables like runningTotal, currentNumber if you use the = button

Answer (score 0):

```
            <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        table.calc {
             border: 2px solid #0034D1;
             background-color: #809FFF;
        }
        input.calc {
             width: 100%;
             margin: 5px;
        }
        </style>

        <script>
        function pushButton(buttonValue) {
             if (buttonValue == 'C') {
                  document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
             }
             else {//this is where most changes occured
                    var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
                    x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
                    document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
             }
        }
        function calculate(equation) {
             var answer = eval(equation);
             document.getElementById('screen').value = answer;
        }

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <table class="calc" cellpadding=4>
        <tr><td colspan=3><input class="calc" id="screen" value='0'type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=1 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=2 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=3 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='/' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=4 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=5 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=6 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='*' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=7 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=8 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=9 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='-' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=0 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='.' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='C' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='+' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan=3><input class="calc" type="button" value='=' onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('screen').value);"></td></tr>
        </table>

        </body>
        </html
```

this does what u want excepts displays a 0 when u clr the page. i made sure to make the values int before adding them together.

Comment: GGG: No. I'm from Denmark, and my gramme is certainly not good. I sorry for the misspelled words or sentences.

Comment: @user1410965 it was directed at GreenGiant, not "u."

Comment: @GreenGiant - Is it possible to make i work with values like 1,0456?

Comment: @user 1410965 is that suppose to be a decimal or comma? and no it won't work with those values since when u click the button it automatically adds it to the value on the screen. this is the way you set it up. IF you wanted to use 1,0456 you would need to have an equal button otherwise the program won't know when you are done with the number. also if this is exactly what you are looking for could you accept the answer?